# Linux create swap using dd: swapon failed: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, swap

I have a swap file called /dev/dm-1 with 1G size, try to increase the size of the swap file to 4G using the steps below:

1. Turn off swap: `swapoff /dev/dm-1`
2. Remove old swap file:
   `rm /dev/dm-1`
3. Create swap file using `dd` comand: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/dm-1 count=4096 bs=1MiB status=progress`
4. Restrict privelages: `chmod 600 /dev/dm-1`
5. Setting up swapspace: `mkswap /dev/dm-1`
6. Start swap: `swapon /dev/dm-1`

**After starting up swap that show error `swapon failed: Invalid argument`**

I using `SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19)` and filesystem is `ext4`

Can someone help?

Comment: Check `dmesg`. Does `mkswap` succeeded?

Comment: In dmesg show the old swap whitch size 1G Adding 999420k swap on /dev/dm-1.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:999420k FS

Comment: Is `/dev/dm-1` really a file? Isn't it a device? It's very odd to create a file in `/dev`. Do not do it, `/dev` should be mounted as `devtmpfs`, you could be basically creating a swap file in memory and calling it swap.... Do not create regular files in `/dev`. Create the swap file somewhere else, like in `/srv`. What does `stat /dev/dm-1` output? What does `findmnt /dev` output?

Comment: `swapon failed: Invalid argument` basically means: "This filesystem doens't support swap files". As KumilCuk already pointed oout, `/dev` normally is mounted as `tmpfs`, which obviously is not a good place for swapfiles

Comment: /dev/dm-1 is a logical volume. You should increase it with lvextend

Comment: Output of stat /dev/dm-1  :  File: /dev/dm-1
  Size: 4294967296      Blocks: 4320       IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 19659       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)

Comment: After I add swap using dd it's created without filesystem type, I change it and aow I got a new error: swapon: /dev/dm-1: skipping - it appears to have holes.
But I using the dd command as all recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, KamilCuk I create a swap in /srv directory and all works now.

> Is `/dev/dm-1` really a file? Isn't it a device? It's very odd to
> create a file in `/dev`. Do not do it, `/dev` should be mounted as
> `devtmpfs`, you could be basically creating a swap file in memory and
> calling it swap.... Do not create regular files in `/dev`. Create the
> swap file somewhere else, like in `/srv`. What does `stat /dev/dm-1`
> output? What does `findmnt /dev` output? – KamilCuk